# Do I really need to re-activate my own Windows 8.1 installation in case of a transplant (aka salvaged) HDD?

Tags: windows-8.1, motherboard, bios, windows-activation

My old laptop **(HP Pavilion dv2)** was getting too slow, too old and it failed occassionally. I was able to physically extract the HDD, so, I got a new but previously owned laptop, without a hard drive. This laptop (Toshiba L340) used to have another Windows HDD in it.

I just popped in **my** HDD, it booted up, and everything seemed A-OK, hunky dory, smooth as silk.
But now, I see occassionally blue screens flashing past, not BSOD but a lighter blue, telling me I should activate **Windows 8.1.** Is this really necessary? I do have the 25-character key.

I remember reading somewhere that the Windows key is written to the BIOS, so, somewhere unto the motherboard. Can this really be true?

Please advise me on how to resolve this. I really don't want to have to pay twice for the same version Windows, just because the hardware failed.

Answer (score 2):

The chances are very high that your license for Windows 8 is an OEM license.

Therefore, you cannot move it to a different machine (which is why it will not activate).

Since this new (used) computer is faster, put Windows 10 on it. Likely you will have to purchase a Windows 10 license (try it) but better to pay for a supported product.

**Note:**  You may be able to back up your data, use the original disk in the Toshiba and upgrade for free.

Comment: it seems unfair that failed hardware forces one to spend money on new software.

Comment: I have gone through this with Microsoft (a variety of ways). OEM licenses are tied to hardware and cannot be moved. That is something that should be clearer to purchasers but that is the way it is.

Comment: If you have the original Toshiba drive (even if you don't) you may be able to upgrade it to Windows 10 for free. Then recover the data from your old drive.

Answer (score 1):

> But now, I see occassionally blue screens flashing past, not BSOD but a lighter blue, telling me I should activate Windows 8.1. Is this really necessary? I do have the 25-character key.

It absolutely is required.  Only the HP Pavilion dv2 was licensed to run Windows 8.1, your Toshiba L340, is licensed for an unspecified version of Windows.

> I remember reading somewhere that the Windows key is written to the BIOS, so, somewhere unto the motherboard. Can this really be true?

The Windows 8.1 (OEM) license was stored in the ACPI table on the HP Pavilion dv2 and cannot be transferred to the Toshiba.

> Please advise me on how to resolve this. I really don't want to have to pay twice for the same version Windows, just because the hardware failed.

Purchase a new Windows license

Comment: I tried this a few more times, and switched the disk from GPT to MBR, and now it just works. Seems that ACPI thingee is not ás effective thán (...thén...) ..... ;-)